# Uncaught ReferenceError: VueBootstrapDatetimePicker is not defined con vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker y VueJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estoy declarando como componente global mi data picker, según la documentación de https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker pero me da error justamente en la linea donde lo declaro como global, es problema es que uso varias veces el componente datapicker en varias partes de mi aplicacion por lo que me dab este error

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <data-picker> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

**por lo cual me dara este error si uso las etiquetas `<date-picker>` mas de una vez**

intente solucionarlo haciendo esto, pero me sigue dando errores

Vue.component('proyecto-fecha-entrega', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker);
Vue.component('fechaProyecto', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker);
Vue.component('date-picker-edit-tarea', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker);

Segun la documentacion la forma de declararlo correctamente seria de esta forma

```
 Vue.component('date-picker', VueBootstrapDatetimePicker);
```

Comment: Según la documentación, con todos los enlaces que están ahí [funcionan correctamente](https://jsfiddle.net/rnfyzt9j/). ¿ Añadió todas las dependencias? ¿Está utilizando Webpack?

Comment: no uso web pack

Comment: todos los data picker me funcionan lo aclaro, pero me dan esos errores en consola

Comment: Debería funcionar como lo muestro en el comentario anterior, fuera de eso quizá añade el componente sin antes agregarlo globalmente, además verifique los nombres de los componentes cuando utilice `components { }` deben ser iguales si no también muestra el error.  Sin más detalles para mi es imposible saber el error, son solo suposiciones.

Comment: me gustaria ver el componente donde estas usando esto.

Comment: Según el error, creo que no le has dicho al componente padre que va a usar ese componente. ¿Podemos ver el componente donde lo llamas?